# ChoiceField vs TypedChoiceField (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, drop-down-menu, django-admin

I read the documentation about [**ChoiceField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) and [**TypedChoiceField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield) but I could only understand that both can create **Dropdown Single Select Box** which looks exactly the same as shown below:

[image]

The code with **ChoiceField** below:

```py
FRUITS = (
    (1,'Apple'),
    (2,'Orange'),
    (3,'Banana')
)

fruits = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FRUITS) # Here
```

The code with **TypedChoiceField** below:

```py
FRUITS = (
    (1,'Apple'),
    (2,'Orange'),
    (3,'Banana')
)

fruits = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=FRUITS) # Here
```

My questions:

1. What is the difference between **ChoiceField** and **TypedChoiceField**?
2. When to use **ChoiceField** and **TypedChoiceField**?

Answer (score 0):

**TypedChoiceField has one extra required argument:**

choices: Either an iterable of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field or a callable that returns such an iterable. This argument accepts the same formats as the choices argument to a model field.

**TypedChoiceField has two optional arguments:**

coerce A function that takes one argument and returns a coerced value. Examples include the built-in int, float, bool and other types. Defaults to an identity function.
empty_value: The value to use to represent “empty.” Defaults to the empty string; None is another common choice here.